# Select sum of an array column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

If I have the following table:

```
Table "users"
Column          |       Type       | Modifiers 
---------------+------------------+-----------
  id            | integer          | 
  monthly_usage | real[]           |
```

Where `monthly_usage` is an array of 12 numbers, i.e. `{1.2, 1.3, 6.2, 0.9,...}`

How can I select the sum of that column?

Something along the lines of:

`SELECT id, sum(monthly_usage) as total_usage from users;`

Which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
SELECT id, (SELECT SUM(s) FROM UNNEST(monthly_usage) s) as total_usage from users;
```

Answer (score 9):

This generalization and reformatting [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729139/dmitry-seleznev)'s answer helps me understand how it works:

```
SELECT
  sum(a) AS total
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      unnest(array [1,2,3]) AS a
  ) AS b
```

Result:

```
total
 6
```

Answer (score 1):

In several ways to add up the values ​​of the array, the form I always use is:

```
WITH X AS(
    SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1, 5, 0, 12, 1, 0, 30, 20, 8, 3, 15, 15, 20, 8]) AS VALOR
)
SELECT SUM(VALOR) FROM X
```

Result:

```
138
```

For more information https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a more "functional" solution, this works well for any sum-able quantity:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sum(
    IN array_in ANYARRAY
,   OUT array_sum ANYELEMENT
) AS
$$
DECLARE
BEGIN

SELECT
    sum(a)
INTO array_sum
FROM unnest(array_in) a
;

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE
;
```

examples:

`array_sum('{1,2,3}'::INT[])`

> 6

`array_sum('{1.1,2.2,3.3}'::NUMERIC[])`

> 6.6

`array_sum('{1 day, 2 day, 3 day}'::INTERVAL[])`

> 0 years 0 mons 6 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs`

`array_sum('{1,2,3}'::TEXT[])`

> ERROR!